# Nested Update panel problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, nested

I am having a nested update panel
something like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="DetailsUpdatePanel" runat="server" Visible="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div><ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="BrochureUpload" Width="400px"   
            OnClientUploadError="BrochureuploadError"    
            OnClientUploadStarted="BrochureStartUpload"  
            OnClientUploadComplete="BrochureUploadComplete"  
            CompleteBackColor="Lime" UploaderStyle="Modern"    
            ErrorBackColor="Red" ClientIDMode="AutoID"    
            ThrobberID="Throbber"    
            UploadingBackColor="#66CCFF" 
                onuploadedcomplete="BrochureUpload_UploadedComplete"/>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Style="display: none">
     <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/uploading.gif" />
            </asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="brochurelblstatus" runat="server" Style="font-family: Arial; font-size: small;"></asp:Label></div>
     <div><asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="child" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                <div>
     <asp:GridView ID=GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="1" DataKeyNames="ArticleId">
        <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="ArticleId" HeaderText="ArticleId" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="td1" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="td2" />
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BrochureUrl">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEPhoto" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" NavigateUrl='<%# GetUrl(Eval("ArticleId"),Eval("FileName")) %>'
                    Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
          </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRemove" runat="server" text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="DeleteOrNo()">
       </asp:LinkButton>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
           </div>

                </ContentTemplate>

                </asp:UpdatePanel></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </updatePanel>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void BrochureUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
                 {
                     if(BrochureUpload.HasFile)
                     {
                         if(BrochureUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength<=3670016 )
                         {
                             var brochurePath = MapPath("~/") + Path.GetFileName(e.filename);
                             BrochureUpload.SaveAs(brochurePath);
                             using (var dataContext = new NewsStandAloneDataContext(Config.StandaloneNewsConnectionString))
                             {
                                 var brochure = new xxx
                                                    {
                                                        Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedValue),
                                                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(e.filename),
                                                        RecordCreated = DateTime.Now
                                                    };
                                 dataContext.xxx.InsertOnSubmit(brochure);
                                 dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                             }
                             bindGridView();//I have code to bind gridview
    Child.Update();


                         }
                     }
                 }

     protected void bindBrochureGridView()
            {
                using (var dataContext = new NewsStandAloneDataContext(Config.StandaloneNewsConnectionString))
                {
                    var brochureList = (from brochure in dataContext.xxx
                                        where brochure.ArticleId == Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.SelectedValue)
                                        select new ArcticleBrochure
                                                   {
                                                       ArticleId = brochure.ArticleId.ToString(),
                                                       FileName = brochure.FileName

                                                   }).ToList();
                    GridView1.DataSource = brochureList;
                    GridView1.DataBind();        

                }
            }
```

When I upload the file , I want the giedview which is in the child updatepanel to be updated .But it doesnt work Any ideas?????

thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, edit your question, it's impossible to understand what's going on, and place code comments in order to guide us about what you're doing there! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `child.Update();` in   `BrochureUpload_UploadedComplete` event.

```
 protected void BrochureUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
 {
   ....................
   ....................
   bindGridView();//I have code to bind gridview
   child.Update();
 }
```

Comment: What no use, I have not get you ? You mean, you have done without calling child.update() method ?

Comment: Hey I have done child.upate() in my code and still i face the same problem

Comment: In your code , I can't see that you call update child.update(); you have to call this method after this statement.  bindGridView();//I have code to bind gridview. Otherwise it will not be updated.

Comment: Hello aktar I hae edited the question with What i have done Inlcuding 'child.update()' but why do i face the same problem again .

Comment: one last thing you can try is, set <asp:UpdatePanel ID="DetailsUpdatePanel" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" I hope this will do the trick.

Comment: Are you able to resolve the issue or still getting the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

When file upload is complete then call `Child.Update()` method of `UpdatePanel` which contain gridview. You need to do that because you set `UpdateMode="Conditional"` in this case you have to manually update it in code.

Comment: have you updated your gridview? first you have to update your girdview then call update method.

Comment: Why you have posted `GridView1` code, it is not in html code?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Use beakpoint on `Child.Update();`
 to check that it  is executing. If yes that means your grid has no updated data, in that case check your database, has it new inserted values?

Answer (score 0):

`ChildrenAsTriggers="True"` in your updatepanel.

Comment: k i will try it and come back to you

Comment: Ho wait, your updatepanels are set to conditionnal, and I cant see any update call in your codebehind. When a updatepanel is set to conditionnal, you need to set triggers or mannual call and update. Also, I would name your 2nd updatepanel differently, because an updatepanel has a "updatepanel.child"

Comment: Hey david sorry when i was typing to ask this question it came out like this "//I have code to bindgridview child.update" came out like comment but in my actual code i have done child.update and still i get the same problem and you knw if i place a button in the panel and update the child update panel in the click event it works perfectly what is the problem with the asyncfileUpload??????.Also I renamed the panel and still the problem continues Please tell me what triggers I should add Please

Comment: `ChildrenAsTriggers` is `true` by default for `UpdatePanel`.