# Nested Update panel update child problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nested Update panel problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990622/nested-update-panel-problem)

Hi All., Iam having a nested update panel something like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="DetailsUpdatePanel" runat="server" Visible="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <ajaxtoolkit:asyncfileupload runat="server" id="BrochureUpload" width="400px" onclientuploaderror="BrochureuploadError" onclientuploadstarted="BrochureStartUpload" onclientuploadcomplete="BrochureUploadComplete" completebackcolor="Lime" uploaderstyle="Modern" errorbackcolor="Red" clientidmode="AutoID" throbberid="Throbber" uploadingbackcolor="#66CCFF" onuploadedcomplete="BrochureUpload_UploadedComplete" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/uploading.gif" />
            </asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="brochurelblstatus" runat="server" Style="font-family: Arial; font-size: small;"></asp:Label></div>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="child" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <asp:GridView ID='GridView2" ' runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="1" DataKeyNames="ArticleId">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ArticleId" HeaderText="ArticleId" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="td1" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="td2" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BrochureUrl">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEPhoto" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" NavigateUrl='<%# GetUrl(Eval("ArticleId"),Eval("FileName")) %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRemove" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="DeleteOrNo()">
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</updatePanel>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void BrochureUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(BrochureUpload.HasFile) { 

        if(BrochureUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength<=3670016 ) { 
            var brochurePath = MapPath("~/") + Path.GetFileName(e.filename); 

            BrochureUpload.SaveAs(brochurePath); 

            using (var dataContext = new NewsStandAloneDataContext(Config.StandaloneNewsConnectionString)) { 

                var brochure = new xxx { Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedValue), 
                                         FileName = Path.GetFileName(e.filename), 
                                         RecordCreated = DateTime.Now }; 

                dataContext.xxx.InsertOnSubmit(brochure); 
                dataContext.SubmitChanges(); 

            } 

            bindGridView();

            //I have code to bind gridview 
            Child.Update(); 

        }

    }

} 

protected void bindBrochureGridView() { 

    using (var dataContext = new NewsStandAloneDataContext(Config.StandaloneNewsConnectionString)) { 

        var brochureList = (from brochure 
                            in dataContext.xxx 
                            where brochure.ArticleId == Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.SelectedValue) 
                            select new ArcticleBrochure { ArticleId = brochure.ArticleId.ToString(), 
                                                          FileName = brochure.FileName }).ToList(); 

        GridView1.DataSource = brochureList; 
        GridView1.DataBind(); 

    } 

}
```

When I upload the file , I want the giedview which is in the child updatepanel to be updated .But it doesnt work Any ideas?????

thanks in advance